# Do I need to patch my ESB (4.8.1)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

The ESB (prod) has the following kernel service packs :

patch0000 to patch0005.

On the http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/carbon/WSO2-CARBON-PATCH-4.2.0/ there are 12 kernel patches.

Do I need to patch the remaining , and do I need to do it one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to added those kernel patches, as those are belong to other products. You may use [WSO2 ESB 4.9.0](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/)

Comment: Thanks, We have just implemented a productions ESB 4.8.1 so going to wait for version 5.0.0 (Camel) , !**scared face**!

Comment: AFAIK, results are very promising.